# Unexpected behaviour using function pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

hope everyone one is doing well.

Just out here seeing the craziest programming behaviour I have ever seen, I was wondering if anyone can explain why is this happening?

I finally just finished rewriting how UART packets from an ESP32 is processed within the [STM32H753ZI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753zi.html) with an array that holds address of functions.

Depending on which packet arrives, for example "0x03" which is "enable line-in input" it will access that function within the function pointer array at the index of the packet, so in this case the "functionPointerArray[[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xekIm.jpg)]"

Whats happening is that when I comment out this piece of code:

```
void I2S_MuteHandler() {

     /* SPI1 -> CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSUSP;
      SPI3 -> CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSUSP;
      while (((SPI1 -> CR1) & (SPI_CR1_CSTART)));
      while (((SPI3 -> CR1) & (SPI_CR1_CSTART)));
      DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_EN;
      DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_EN;
      DMA1_Stream3 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_EN;
      SPI1 -> CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;
      SPI3 -> CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;*/
    }
```

The output wave of which processed through a DSP code and sent out via "I2S3_TxBUFF" of code:

```
void I2S_HALFCOMPLETE_CALLBACK() {

    int * I2S1_RxBUFF = getI2S1_RxBUFF();
    int * I2S1_TxBUFF = getI2S1_TxBUFF();
    int * I2S3_TxBUFF = getI2S3_TxBUFF();

    double INSAMPLE_I2S_L[1024];
    double INSAMPLE_I2S_R[1024];
    double INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[2048];

    double OUTSAMPLE_I2S_L[1024];
    double OUTSAMPLE_I2S_R[1024];
    double OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[2048];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i += 2) {

        //EVEN
        INSAMPLE_I2S_L[(i >> 1)] = (double)I2S1_RxBUFF[i] * (double)ADC_COMPENSATOR * 0.01 * centers.volume * centers.inputCompensator;
        INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i] = (double)((I2S1_RxBUFF[i] + I2S1_RxBUFF[i+1]) >> 1) * (double)ADC_COMPENSATOR * 0.01 * subwoofers.volume;
        //ODD
        INSAMPLE_I2S_R[(i >> 1)] = (double)I2S1_RxBUFF[i+1] * (double)ADC_COMPENSATOR * 0.01 * centers.volume * centers.inputCompensator;
        INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i+1] = INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i];
    }

    arm_biquad_cascade_df2T_f64(&subwoofers.audioStream_MONO, INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO, OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO, 2048);
    arm_biquad_cascade_df2T_f64(&centers.audioStream_L, INSAMPLE_I2S_L, OUTSAMPLE_I2S_L, 1024);
    arm_biquad_cascade_df2T_f64(&centers.audioStream_R, INSAMPLE_I2S_R, OUTSAMPLE_I2S_R, 1024);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2048; i += 2){

        //EVEN
        I2S1_TxBUFF[i] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_L[i >> 1];
        I2S3_TxBUFF[i] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i];
        //ODD
        I2S1_TxBUFF[i+1] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_R[i >> 1];
        I2S3_TxBUFF[i+1] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i+1];
    }
}

void I2S_TRANSFERCOMPLETE_CALLBACK() {

    int * I2S1_RxBUFF = getI2S1_RxBUFF();
    int * I2S1_TxBUFF = getI2S1_TxBUFF();
    int * I2S3_TxBUFF = getI2S3_TxBUFF();

    double INSAMPLE_I2S_L[1024];
    double INSAMPLE_I2S_R[1024];
    double INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[2048];

    double OUTSAMPLE_I2S_L[1024];
    double OUTSAMPLE_I2S_R[1024];
    double OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[2048];

    for (int i = 2048; i < 4096; i += 2) {

      //EVEN
      INSAMPLE_I2S_L[(i >> 1)-1024] = (double)I2S1_RxBUFF[i] * (double)ADC_COMPENSATOR * 0.01 * (double)centers.volume * centers.inputCompensator;
      INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i-2048] = (double)((I2S1_RxBUFF[i] + I2S1_RxBUFF[i+1]) >> 1) * (double)ADC_COMPENSATOR * 0.01 * subwoofers.volume;
      //ODD
      INSAMPLE_I2S_R[(i >> 1)-1024] = (double)I2S1_RxBUFF[i+1] * (double)ADC_COMPENSATOR * 0.01 * (double)centers.volume * centers.inputCompensator;
      INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[(i+1)-2048] =  INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i-2048];
  }

        arm_biquad_cascade_df2T_f64(&subwoofers.audioStream_MONO, INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO, OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO, 2048);
        arm_biquad_cascade_df2T_f64(&centers.audioStream_L, INSAMPLE_I2S_L, OUTSAMPLE_I2S_L, 1024);
        arm_biquad_cascade_df2T_f64(&centers.audioStream_R, INSAMPLE_I2S_R, OUTSAMPLE_I2S_R, 1024);

  for (int i = 2048 ; i < 4096; i += 2){

        //EVEN
        I2S1_TxBUFF[i] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_L[(i >> 1)-1024];
        I2S3_TxBUFF[i] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i-2048];
        //ODD
        I2S1_TxBUFF[i+1] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_R[(i >> 1)-1024];
        I2S3_TxBUFF[i+1] = (int)OUTSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[(i+1)-2048];
  }
}
```

makes the input sine wave look like square waves and the biquad filters stop working
[image]

and when I uncomment the code thats causing the issue, the wave is working perfectly and the biquad filters work.
[image]

For a better in-depth look i'll include how I populate the array of function pointers and how it executes.

The function pointer array gets populated during the initialization stage of the MCU along side its peripherals CODE:

```
void load_functionHandlers() {

    messageReceived[0] = I2S_MuteHandler; // I believe the issue stems here in this function
    messageReceived[1] = I2S_UnmuteHandler;
//  messageReceived[2] = SPDIF_MuteHandler;
//  messageReceived[3] = SPDIF_UnmuteHandler;

    messageReceived[3] = audioSelectorInlineHandler;
//  messageReceived[5] = audioSelectorBluetoothHandler;
//  messageReceived[6] = audioSelectorSPDIFHandler;
//  messageReceived[7] = audioSelectorHDMIHandler;

//  messageReceived[8] = audioSelectorInternalHandler;
//  messageReceived[9] = audioSelectorExternalHandler;

//  messageReceived[10] = setupIRHandler;
//  messageReceived[11] = disableTouchHandler;
//  messageReceived[12] = enableTouchHandler;

//  messageReceived[13] = nightRiderLightsHandler;
//  messageReceived[14] = rainbowLightsHandler;

    messageReceived[15] = volumeIncreaseHandler;
    messageReceived[16] = volumeDecreaseHandler;
//
    messageReceived[17] = n_12dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[18] = n_9dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[19] = n_6dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[20] = n_3dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[21] = _0dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[22] = p_3dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[23] = p_6dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[24] = p_9dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[25] = p_12dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[26] =   n_12dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[27] =   n_9dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[28] =   n_6dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[29] =   n_3dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[30] =   _0dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[31] =   p_3dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[32] =   p_6dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[33] =   p_9dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[34] =   p_12dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[35] =   n_12dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[36] =   n_9dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[37] =   n_6dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[38] =   n_3dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[39] =   _0dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[40] =   p_3dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[41] =   p_6dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[42] =   p_9dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[43] =   p_12dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[44] =   n_12dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[45] =   n_9dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[46] =   n_6dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[47] =   n_3dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[48] =   _0dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[49] =   p_3dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[50] =   p_6dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[51] =   p_9dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[52] =   p_12dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[53] =   n_12dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[54] =   n_9dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[55] =   n_6dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[56] =   n_3dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[57] =   _0dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[58] =   p_3dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[59] =   p_6dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[60] =   p_9dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[61] =   p_12dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[62] =   n_12dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[63] =   n_9dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[64] =   n_6dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[65] =   n_3dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[66] =   _0dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[67] =   p_3dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[68] =   p_6dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[69] =   p_9dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[70] =   p_12dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[71] =   n_12dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[72] =   n_9dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[73] =   n_6dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[74] =   n_3dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[75] =   _0dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[76] =   p_3dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[77] =   p_6dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[78] =   p_9dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[79] =   p_12dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[80] =   n_12dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[81] =   n_9dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[82] =   n_6dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[83] =   n_3dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[84] =   _0dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[85] =   p_3dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[86] =   p_6dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[87] =   p_9dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[88] =   p_12dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;

    //messageReceived[89] = disableLightsHandler;
}
```

How the function pointer gets executed CODE:

```
  static void (*messageReceived[255])(void); // Global Variable 
    
    
    void UART4_TRANSFERCOMPELTE_CALLBACK(uint8_t exitPacket) {
        //functions pointers
        if (exitPacket) {

        if ((exitPacket >= 0) && (exitPacket <= 88)) {
            (*messageReceived[exitPacket])();
        }



    } else {

        uint8_t packet = getUART4_RxBUFF()[0];

        if ((packet >= 0) && (packet <= 88)) {
            (*messageReceived[packet])();
        }
}
    }
```

I can't never predict the behaviour of this. I try commenting out random function pointers where the function pointers get populated into the array and it works, and vice versa

I thought it was a memory address being overwritten somewhere, however I double checked the the two address of when the wave is square and when the wave is perfect. Its registers, address, anything you name it are identical. I am mind blown right now. If anyone can shine light on this would be amazing. It doesnt even enter the function thats in question at all

I know its an issue where populating the array is happening as when I do this test code to bypass the function pointer and comment out out the block of code it doesnt work still.

```
static void (*messageReceived[255])(void);


void UART4_TRANSFERCOMPELTE_CALLBACK(uint8_t exitPacket) {
    //functions pointers
    uint8_t * packet;


    if (exitPacket) {
        packet = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
        packet[0] = exitPacket;

    } else {
        packet = getUART4_RxBUFF();
    }

    //(*messageReceived[packet[0]])(); // By passing function pointer array
    audioSelectorInlineHandler();

}
```

UPDATE 1:

If I once again bypass the function pointer array and comment EVERYTHING in the function that populates the function pointer array. It works
CODE:

```
/*
 * UART_PACKET_PROCESSOR.c
 *
 *  Created on: May 13, 2021
 *      Author: Christopher
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <constants.h>
#include <dspFactory.h>
#include <inputSourceFactory.h>
#include <opcode.h>
#include <packetProcessor.h>
#include <uartFactory.h>

static void (*messageReceived[255])(void);


void UART4_TRANSFERCOMPELTE_CALLBACK(uint8_t exitPacket) {
    //functions pointers
    uint8_t * packet = NULL;


    if (exitPacket) {
        //(*messageReceived[packet[exitPacket]])();


    } else {
        //(*messageReceived[getUART4_RxBUFF()[0]])();
    }


    audioSelectorInlineHandler();

}

void load_functionHandlers() {

//  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
//      messageReceived[i] = 0;
//  }
//
//  messageReceived[0] = &I2S_MuteHandler;
//  messageReceived[1] = &I2S_UnmuteHandler;
////    messageReceived[2] = SPDIF_MuteHandler;
////    messageReceived[3] = SPDIF_UnmuteHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[3] = &audioSelectorInlineHandler;
////    messageReceived[5] = audioSelectorBluetoothHandler;
////    messageReceived[6] = audioSelectorSPDIFHandler;
////    messageReceived[7] = audioSelectorHDMIHandler;
//
////    messageReceived[8] = audioSelectorInternalHandler;
////    messageReceived[9] = audioSelectorExternalHandler;
//
////    messageReceived[10] = setupIRHandler;
////    messageReceived[11] = disableTouchHandler;
////    messageReceived[12] = enableTouchHandler;
//
////    messageReceived[13] = nightRiderLightsHandler;
////    messageReceived[14] = rainbowLightsHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[15] = &volumeIncreaseHandler;
//  messageReceived[16] = &volumeDecreaseHandler;
////
//  messageReceived[17] = &n_12dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[18] = &n_9dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[19] = &n_6dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[20] = &n_3dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[21] = &_0dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[22] = &p_3dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[23] = &p_6dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[24] = &p_9dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[25] = &p_12dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[26] =   &n_12dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//    messageReceived[27] = &n_9dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//    messageReceived[28] = &n_6dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[29] =   &n_3dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[30] =   &_0dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[31] =   &p_3dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[32] =   &p_6dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[33] =   &p_9dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[34] =   &p_12dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[35] =   &n_12dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[36] =   &n_9dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//    messageReceived[37] = &n_6dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[38] =   &n_3dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[39] =   &_0dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[40] =   &p_3dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[41] =   &p_6dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[42] =   &p_9dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[43] =   &p_12dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[44] =   &n_12dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[45] =   &n_9dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//    messageReceived[46] = &n_6dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[47] =   &n_3dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[48] =   &_0dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[49] =   &p_3dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[50] =   &p_6dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[51] =   &p_9dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[52] =   &p_12dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[53] =   &n_12dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[54] =   &n_9dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//    messageReceived[55] = &n_6dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[56] =   &n_3dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[57] =   &_0dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[58] =   &p_3dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[59] =   &p_6dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[60] =   &p_9dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[61] =   &p_12dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[62] =   &n_12dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[63] =   &n_9dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[64] =   &n_6dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[65] =   &n_3dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[66] =   &_0dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[67] =   &p_3dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[68] =   &p_6dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[69] =   &p_9dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[70] =   &p_12dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[71] =   &n_12dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[72] =   &n_9dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[73] =   &n_6dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[74] =   &n_3dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[75] =   &_0dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[76] =   &p_3dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[77] =   &p_6dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[78] =   &p_9dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[79] =   &p_12dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
//
//  messageReceived[80] =   &n_12dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[81] =   &n_9dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[82] =   &n_6dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[83] =   &n_3dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[84] =   &_0dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[85] =   &p_3dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[86] =   &p_6dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[87] =   &p_9dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
//  messageReceived[88] =   &p_12dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;

    //messageReceived[89] = disableLightsHandler;
}
```

UPDATE 2:

If I tried another function to comment out and it still does the same behaviour.

CODE:

```
void load_functionHandlers() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        messageReceived[i] = 0;
    }

    messageReceived[0] = &I2S_MuteHandler;
    messageReceived[1] = &I2S_UnmuteHandler; //Comment this shows same behavoir
//  messageReceived[2] = SPDIF_MuteHandler;
//  messageReceived[3] = SPDIF_UnmuteHandler;

    messageReceived[3] = &audioSelectorInlineHandler;
//  messageReceived[5] = audioSelectorBluetoothHandler;
//  messageReceived[6] = audioSelectorSPDIFHandler;
//  messageReceived[7] = audioSelectorHDMIHandler;

//  messageReceived[8] = audioSelectorInternalHandler;
//  messageReceived[9] = audioSelectorExternalHandler;

//  messageReceived[10] = setupIRHandler;
//  messageReceived[11] = disableTouchHandler;
//  messageReceived[12] = enableTouchHandler;

//  messageReceived[13] = nightRiderLightsHandler;
//  messageReceived[14] = rainbowLightsHandler;

    messageReceived[15] = &volumeIncreaseHandler; // no affect
    messageReceived[16] = &volumeDecreaseHandler; // no affect
//
    messageReceived[17] = &n_12dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler; ////////
    messageReceived[18] = &n_9dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[19] = &n_6dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[20] = &n_3dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[21] = &_0dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[22] = &p_3dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler; any of these shows same behavior
    messageReceived[23] = &p_6dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[24] = &p_9dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler; 
    messageReceived[25] = &p_12dB_subBass_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[26] =   &n_12dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[27] =   &n_9dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler; 
    messageReceived[28] =   &n_6dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[29] =   &n_3dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[30] =   &_0dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[31] =   &p_3dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[32] =   &p_6dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[33] =   &p_9dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[34] =   &p_12dB_Bass_notch_EQHandler;    
    messageReceived[35] =   &n_12dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[36] =   &n_9dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[37] =   &n_6dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler; 
    messageReceived[38] =   &n_3dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[39] =   &_0dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[40] =   &p_3dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[41] =   &p_6dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[42] =   &p_9dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[43] =   &p_12dB_lower_midrange_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[44] =   &n_12dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[45] =   &n_9dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[46] =   &n_6dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[47] =   &n_3dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler; any of these shows same behavior
    messageReceived[48] =   &_0dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[49] =   &p_3dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[50] =   &p_6dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[51] =   &p_9dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[52] =   &p_12dB_midrange_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[53] =   &n_12dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[54] =   &n_9dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[55] =   &n_6dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[56] =   &n_3dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler; any of these shows same behavior
    messageReceived[57] =   &_0dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[58] =   &p_3dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[59] =   &p_6dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[60] =   &p_9dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[61] =   &p_12dB_higher_midrange_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[62] =   &n_12dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[63] =   &n_9dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[64] =   &n_6dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[65] =   &n_3dB_presence_notch_EQHandler; any of these shows same behavior
    messageReceived[66] =   &_0dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[67] =   &p_3dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[68] =   &p_6dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[69] =   &p_9dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[70] =   &p_12dB_presence_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[71] =   &n_12dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[72] =   &n_9dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[73] =   &n_6dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[74] =   &n_3dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[75] =   &_0dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[76] =   &p_3dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler; any of these shows same behavior
    messageReceived[77] =   &p_6dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[78] =   &p_9dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[79] =   &p_12dB_brilliance_notch_EQHandler;

    messageReceived[80] =   &n_12dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[81] =   &n_9dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[82] =   &n_6dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[83] =   &n_3dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[84] =   &_0dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler; any of these shows same behavior
    messageReceived[85] =   &p_3dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[86] =   &p_6dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[87] =   &p_9dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler;
    messageReceived[88] =   &p_12dB_Bass_lowShelf_EQHandler; ////////////

    //messageReceived[89] = disableLightsHandler;
}
```

Comment: If your question is on-topic here then you should ask it here.

Comment: Oh yeah? Okay even if its embedded?

Comment: what is the point of mallocking one byte? You just waste time and leak memory

Comment: In the last bit you say the code doesn't work properly even when you are not using the function pointers, that suggests the function pointers are not the cause of the problem

Comment: @M.M just wasn't sure if I need to allocated memory or not. Does "uint8_t * packet" doesnt need to be malloc? I see its not the issue?

Comment: Maybe you're calling function ```I2S_MuteHandler``` somewhere else and commenting code out affects it?

Comment: @MarkSouls I put a breakpoint. The function never reaches in the entirety of the program life cycle as I have never called it yet (Its not implemented yet)

Comment: just call `messagereceived[exitPacket]();` instead of malloc one byte blah blah , you can use `exitPacket` or have another local uint8_t

Comment: @M.M ahh Gotchu king, understood ill change that up in code

Comment: @M.M I either miswrote the last part or you misunderstood. What I mean by that is if I play around with the load_functionHandlers() it can work or dont work. Maybe nothing to do with function pointer but something is up within that function handler

Comment: Off topic but they say you shouldn't use dynamic allocation in embedded, though I don't exactly know your situation.

Comment: @MarkSouls uhhh I guess but if youre freeing it and have a lot of memory you should be good

Comment: probably you read or write out of bounds of an array somewhere in the program

Comment: @M.M what do you mean?

Comment: You malloc a one (!) byte buffer and you never free it, this is totally wrong and pointless. Your memory will be exhausted sooner or later.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It was pointed out by others and is now fixed, however the issue still there

Comment: @Pllsz it's not fixed in the question however....

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry ill update it.

Comment: @Pllsz the `UART4_TRANSFERCOMPELTE_CALLBACK` occurs twice in your question and they are slightly different. Please clarify....

Comment: Fixed it check it again. Wait unless I am missing something

Comment: It is bad to write out of bounds of an array and can lead to seemingly unrelated strange behaviour due to variables being corrupted

Comment: Where am I writing out of bounds?

Comment: Somewhere in your program, maybe

Comment: The only time the function array pointer gets accessed is within UART4_TRANSFERCOMPELTE_CALLBACK. I have debugged it and only 0x03 gets used as it should be since its been hard programmed to do that.

Comment: What happens if you remove ```I2S_MuteHandler``` completely and assigning it to ```messageReceived[0]```? Does it work well or still buggy?

Comment: Sorry, if you can explain further, how can you assign it if you removed it

Comment: I meant removing assigning part too.

Comment: I believed it work, but I gotta double check. If it does work what would that mean?

Comment: @MarkSouls its still buggy

Comment: Try uncommenting one line at a time and find at which line it begin to work

Comment: This is a cross post, the [other question is here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/571749/228879).

Comment: @MarkSouls I took out the comment for I2S_MuteHandler and just commented another handler and it does the samething?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to use C properly, otherwise, the one will be used by C. The code (in a question) suffers from numerous issues, I will emphasize just one: naming.
Thus, I had to assume few things since naming is not logical. Maybe I got it right.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t function_id_type ;

/* valid function index is 0 ... (0xFF-1) */    
#define MAX_FUNCTIONS 255 
/* I assumed bellow has to be in the range above? 
   if not just change the value here
   This first function is for some special purpose
 */    
#define EXIT_PACKET_ID 0

#define VALID_FUNCTION_INDEX(IDX_) \
(IDX_ >= 0 && IDX_ < MAX_FUNCTIONS)

//
function_id_type getUART4_RxBUFF() { 
    // this is OK value as for testing/demo as we have
    // not more that two elements in the function table
    return (function_id_type)1; 
    // this will provoke assert exit downstream
    // return (function_id_type)(MAX_FUNCTIONS + MAX_FUNCTIONS); 
};

// type alias 
// function table made of functions
// to process the messages received
typedef void (*function_table[MAX_FUNCTIONS])(void);

// demo workers
static void I2S_MuteHandler() {}
static void I2S_UnmuteHandler() {}

static void create_function_table ( function_table ft_ )
{
    ft_[0] = I2S_MuteHandler; 
    ft_[1] = I2S_UnmuteHandler;
    // leave the rest empty
}

// full table validity is obviously an expensive operation
#define PARTIALY_VALID_F_TABLE(FT) ( FT && FT[0] && FT[1] )

static void UART4_TRANSFERCOMPELTE_CALLBACK(
    function_id_type exitPacket,
    // due to the arg declaration
    // will have to contain min MAX_FUNCTIONS
    // and can not be null
    void (*function_table[static MAX_FUNCTIONS])(void)) 
{
    assert( PARTIALY_VALID_F_TABLE(function_table) );

  if (exitPacket == EXIT_PACKET_ID) {
    (*function_table[exitPacket])();

  } else {
    const function_id_type packet = getUART4_RxBUFF();
    // in debug builds check before use
    assert(VALID_FUNCTION_INDEX(packet)) ;
    // index is valid but is there a function 
    // under that index
    assert(function_table[packet]) ;
    // all tests passed, use
    (*function_table[packet])();
  }
}

//
int main(void) 
{
    function_table my_ft_ = {0};

    // this call fails on assert as ft is empty
    // UART4_TRANSFERCOMPLETE_CALLBACK(EXIT_PACKET_ID, my_ft_) ;

    create_function_table( my_ft_ ) ;
    
    // OK
    UART4_TRANSFERCOMPLETE_CALLBACK(EXIT_PACKET_ID, my_ft_) ;

    // on this call make sure EXIT_PACKET_ID is not used
    UART4_TRANSFERCOMPLETE_CALLBACK(EXIT_PACKET_ID + 1, my_ft_) ;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

There is nothing tricky or snazzy above and I hope the code is readable, with better naming, and easier to get right for the exact use-case. No Oscilloscope pictures were necessary :)

Also here is the link to the working Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/sa37a6o5a
Note there are no compiler arguments given. Please use them, in your work, after learning them and then if proven necessary.

HTH

Comment: I do appreciate the code rework and I'll study from it for the future, however how does this come closer to solving the problem at hand?

Comment: @Pllsz primary aim is to show you the resilient C. No globals, proper array arguments, type aliases, etc. Just simple but efficient and resilient C. That out of the way + proper naming = SO people, can hope to understand immediately the problem, with no guessing. But then you will understand it too and very likely you will not have C related problems.  Good command of `C`, will solve "the problem at hand" but also many other problems in the future.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the response. Well I always had issues with globals. I just dont know a better way to have a variable to last as long as the program to keep track of states, besides putting it as a global and doing it like that

Comment: The fact is globals are unavoidable. The recommended course of action is to cluster them all in one struct. E.g. `typedef strict { int8_t EXIT_PACKET_ID ; } GLOB`. That will "make them obvious" and make them far easier to manage.

Comment: Right, thank you for the tip. Thats a much better idea.

Comment: ["Modern C"](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) -- Jens Gustedt. Please download this book (it is free) and read it from the first to the last page.